# Cartesian product of fields is semisimple iff the index set is finite

Tags: ring-theory, modules

This question may have already been asked.

> Let $R = \prod_{i\in I} K_i$ where each $K_i$ is a field. Show that
>   $R$ is a semisimple ring iff the index set $I$ is finite.

I think I need to show that the direct product of a finite number of fields, when taken as a module over itself, can be reduced to corresponding to a direct sum of irreducible modules. Can I receive a hint in how to go about doing that?

Comment: Let $f_i:K_i \to R$ be the natural inclusions, where $f_i(k)$ goes to all $0$s except $k$ in the $i^\text{th}$ position.  Then $R$ decomposes into the direct sum of the images $f_i(K_i)$ when the index set is finite.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state which definition of semisimplicity you want to use, and which equivalent versions you already know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that a semisimple ring is Artinian, then obviously $\prod_{i\in I} K_i$ is not Artinian if $I$ is infinite (just create an ascending chain of ideals using the factors you're given.)

If you know what an essential ideal is: $A=\oplus_{i\in I}K_i$ is an essential ideal in $\prod_{i\in I}K_i$, and if $I$ is infinite, $A$ is a *proper* ideal. But a proper essential ideal cannot be a direct summand. All ideals must be summands, of course, in a semisimple ring.

Comment: why is $A=\oplus_{i\in I}K_i$ an essential ideal of $\prod_{i\in I}K_i$,would you mind explaining it in details,thanks!

Comment: @mathrookie Every nonzero element of the product can be multiplied by a ring element to get a nonzero element in the sum.